# Create LCC labels from external file

Tags: sticky-labels, textmerg

I am creating a page of sticky labels containing Library of Congress Classification call numbers (LCCs). They are in what the [`labels` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/labels) calls "plain format".

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
PR
6051
.D3352
M68

Z
253.4
.T47
K58

QA
76.6
.K644

Z
250.8
.M46
E578

PR
5815

PR
6039
.O32
T65
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=10
\LeftPageMargin=4mm
\RightPageMargin=4mm
\TopPageMargin=12.5mm
\BottomPageMargin=13mm
\InterLabelColumn=4mm
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\LeftLabelBorder=0.2mm
\RightLabelBorder=0.2mm
\TopLabelBorder=0.2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels
\LabelInfotrue % show info for labels

\begin{document}
\labelfile{\jobname.dat}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: simple labels, left flush]

However, I actually want to adjust the formatting of the labels so that they are shifted to the right while still being left-aligned. I accomplished this like so:

```
\begin{center}%
\parbox{20mm}{%
PR
6051
.D3352
M68}\end{center}
```

Full text here:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=10
\LeftPageMargin=4mm
\RightPageMargin=4mm
\TopPageMargin=12.5mm
\BottomPageMargin=13mm
\InterLabelColumn=4mm
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\LeftLabelBorder=0.2mm
\RightLabelBorder=0.2mm
\TopLabelBorder=0.2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels
\LabelInfotrue % show info for labels

\begin{document}
\begin{labels}%
\begin{center}%
\parbox{20mm}{%
PR
6051
.D3352
M68}\end{center}

\begin{center}%
\parbox{20mm}{%
Z
253.4
.T47
K58}\end{center}

\begin{center}%
\parbox{20mm}{%
QA
76.6
.K644}\end{center}

\begin{center}%
\parbox{20mm}{%
Z
250.8
.M46
E578}\end{center}

\begin{center}%
\parbox{20mm}{%
PR
5815}\end{center}

\begin{center}%
\parbox{20mm}{%
PR
6039
.O32
T65}\end{center}

\end{labels}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: better formatted labels]

Of course, I still need to read in from the external file. I thought maybe I could modify the `\labelfile` macro to accomplish this. However, when I looked at `labels.sty`, I found it was just a wrapper for `\input`.

```
\def\labelfile#1{\begin{labels}\input#1\end{labels}}
```

So next I tried [`textmerg`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textmerg).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
PR
6051
.D3352
M68

Z
253.4
.T47
K58

QA
76.6
.K644

Z
250.8
.M46
E578

PR
5815

PR
6039
.O32
T65
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{textmerg}

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=10
\LeftPageMargin=4mm
\RightPageMargin=4mm
\TopPageMargin=12.5mm
\BottomPageMargin=13mm
\InterLabelColumn=4mm
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\LeftLabelBorder=0.2mm
\RightLabelBorder=0.2mm
\TopLabelBorder=0.2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels
\LabelInfotrue % show info for labels

\begin{document}
\Fields{\subclass\number\cutter}

\Merge{\jobname.dat}{%
  \addresslabel{
    \begin{center}
    \parbox{20mm}{
      \subclass\\
      \number\\
      \cutter}
    \end{center}
  }%
}%
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, LCCs are variable length; they are typically between two to four lines long. Some have one or more Cutter numbers; some do not. This means the numbers get split up incorrectly.

[image: labels split up incorrectly]

Of the following, what would be the best approach?

- Override the macros in `labels` to get the formatting I want?

  (I wasn't able to find a hint on this in the documentation.)
- Use an advanced feature of `textmerg` to handle the variable-length format?

  (The "complicated example" in the manual deals with a "table of indeterminate length, albeit fixed width". I believe in this case the width is not fixed.)
- Use a different package, such as `datatool`?

  Most of the examples in `datatool` deal with CSVs, so I'm not sure how well this would work.

Here is a link to a git repository to make it easier to get the files:

https://github.com/nbeaver/lcc-label-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `\LeftLabelBorder` to a higher value:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry} % because my default output paper would be A4

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=10
\LeftPageMargin=4mm
\RightPageMargin=4mm
\TopPageMargin=12.5mm
\BottomPageMargin=13mm
\InterLabelColumn=4mm
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\LeftLabelBorder=10mm    % <--- changed
\RightLabelBorder=0.2mm
\TopLabelBorder=0.2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels
\LabelInfotrue % show info for labels

\begin{document}
\labelfile{\jobname.dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't believe I missed such a simple and elegant solution!